# Create Multiple Instances of a Form (and keep them there) in C#

Tags: c#

I'm **very** new to C#, and I'm trying to create a Windows Form Application that would create multiple instances of the same form and keep them in existence, and end them all on a certain keypress. Right now, I'm having some difficulties with keeping said forms from automatically closing. Since I'm new to c#, I have no idea why. I also have no idea where to look for a problem like this, so this question may be a duplicate. Here's my (probably severely butchered) main code so far (from the main file, in this case, Program.cs):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace WindowsFormProgram1
{


    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        /// 
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);


            for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
            {
                new Form1().Show();
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }        
        }
    }
}
```

Any answer would be appreciated greatly. As I mentioned before, I only have a rudimentary understanding of C#, and this may simply be a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is because your code ends sooner than you might think.

```
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {
        new Form1().Show();
        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
    // code exit's here, thus closing all forms created.
}
```

To this, you can add an [`Application.Run()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157900%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) call at the end, which will cause the main thread to wait until the specified [`ApplicationContext`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.applicationcontext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) exits; in most cases the context is a form, as in `Application.Run(new Form1());`, you just need to remember that the main thread will block (i.e. not continue) until `Application.Run` returns. So you could modify your code as such:

```
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++) // <- note 14
    {
        new Form1().Show(); // will show the form
        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
    // This will show the form and block until the form is closed
    Application.Run(new Form1());
}
```

Additionally, since you want to close all forms when a key is pressed, you could do something like the following:

```
public static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        Form1 f = new Form1();
        f.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(f_KeyPress);
        f.Show();
    }
    // Note, no `new Form1()`; this will block until Exit is called.
    Application.Run();
}

static void f_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    // This will exit when ANY key is pressed on ANY form
    Application.Exit();
}
```

These are just a couple of ways to achieve what you want, there's also the [`Form.ShowDialog`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method, but since you're just learning, I'll leave other implementation details up to you.

> I also have no idea where to look for a problem like this

The [.NET Framework Development Guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156542%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has a lot of information on where to start and how to continue, as well the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt472912%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) documentation on the .NET library is the reference to use when you're curious on the syntax or operation of a .NET class/function. There's also the [Object Browser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exy1facf%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) in Visual Studio that lets you view some of brief documentation.

Hope this can help.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering this question, I'll look into it. Also, by my statement of "I have no idea of where to look," I really meant I didn't know what to search up and hence asked this question. Thanks again!